# Unable to fix my helper functions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having a hard time getting my helper functions to work in running the program. This is what I have so far in my program:

```
# create_grades - A function that will create and return a list of
# 'amount' randomly selected between 0 and 100. 0 and 100 are included.
def create_grades(amount):
    import random
    grade_list = []
    for i in range (amount):
        number = random.randint (0, 100)
        grade_list.append (number)
    return grade_list

# print_rows - A function that prints all of grade_list displaying 4 space
# separated values in each row. Last row may have fewer than 4 values in it.
def print_rows(grade_list):
    count = 0
    for i in range (len(grade_list)):
        print(grade_list[i], end = " ")
        if (grade_list[i] % 2 == 0):
            count += 1

# add_grade - A function that gets user input from 0 to 100, and counts how 
# many times the grade occurs in 'grade_list'. Result is printed out.
def add_grade(grade_list):

    grade = int(input("\nEnter a grade between 0 and 100: "))

    print (grade, "occurs", number, "times.")

# count_grades - A function that calculates and returns amount of 2-digit grades
# in grade_list. grade_list is assumed to have at least one value. 
def count_grades(grade_list):
    count = 0
    if (grade_list > 9 and grade_list <= 100):
        count +=1


# Main function - Test all of the helper functions
def test_grades():

    grade_list = create_grades (11)
    print_rows (grade_list)

    add_grade (grade_list)
    print_rows (grade_list)

    print ("Amount of 2-digit values =", count_grades (grade_list))
```

The program has missing pieces here and there because I cant seem to get past my issue with the remaining helper functions. I'm struggling with getting print_rows, add_grade, and count_grades to yield this type of result:

```
test_grades()

47 7 43 90
7 39 97 41
36 100 64

Enter a grade between 0 and 100: 7
7 occurs 3 times

47 7 43 90
7 39 97 41
36 100 64

Amount of 2-digit values = 8
```

Comment: You seem to be asking multiple questions, i.e., why doesn't function A doesn't work, why doesn't function B doesn't work, etc. Each question should focus at one problem at a time. Your bigger picture might be to get your code running, but deep down, there are multiple and different problems you're dealing with.

Comment: When I run the code I get `in add_grade
    print (grade, "occurs", number, "times.")
NameError: global name 'number' is not defined`; `number` variable isn't within this function's scope.

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or Python 3.x?

Comment: Python 2.x @DavidG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using Python 2.7 as that is what you have tagged. This task is easier to do if you break it up into parts to get each of them working individually.

`print_rows` can be modified to print on a new line if count is equal to 3 (python indexing starts at 0). Printing on the same line in python 2.x is don by adding a comma at the end of the print statement:

```
def print_rows(grade_list):
    count = 0
    for i in grade_list:
        if count == 3:
            print i
            count = 0
        else:
            print i,
            count += 1
```

In `add_grade` you need to work out how many time `grade` appears in `grade_list`. This can be done using `grade_list.count(grade)`

```
def add_grade(grade_list):    
    grade = int(input("\nEnter a grade between 0 and 100: "))    
    print grade, "occurs", list(grade_list).count(grade), "time(s)."
```

In `count_grade` you need to filter out the results in the list you don't want then calculate the length of the list using the built-in function `len()`:

```
def count_grades(grade_list):
    two_digit_grades = grade_list[(grade_list > 9) & (grade_list <= 100)]
    return len(two_digit_grades)
```

Also, simplifying your `create_grades` with the use of `numpy`:

```
def create_grades(amount):
    import numpy as np
    return np.random.randint(0, 100, amount)
```

Calling these functions

```
def test_grades():  
    grade_list = create_grades(11)
    print_rows(grade_list)
    add_grade(grade_list)   
    print "Amount of 2-digit values =", count_grades(grade_list)

test_grades()
```

Gives:

```
25 88 93 16
27 53 62 46
28 6 85
Enter a grade between 0 and 100: 88
88 occurs 1 time(s).
Amount of 2-digit values = 10
```

Comment: thank you for your help :)

and for a program like python 3.5, we would print the 'i' in 'print_rows' by using end = " " right?

Comment: @tabi No problem. Don’t forget to upvote and accept this answer if this answers your question